# LinkedIn iOS SDK - [invalid.profile.access]. You don't have access to the profile

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

I have an app that uses LinkedIn for signing users in. Then, it retrieves information about users using the LinkedIn iOS SDK.

I have 2 users, A and B. Both of them are signed into my app, one app instance for each user: InstanceA for user A and InstanceB for user B.

The problem I have is that when I try to retrieve basic profile information for user A from InstanceB, I get the following LinkedIn error.

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "[invalid.profile.access]. You don't have access to the profile",
  "requestId": "BLABLABLA",
  "status": 403,
  "timestamp": 1443251861968
}
```

If I use LinkedIn's `sampleApp` that comes with the LinkedIn iOS SDK, then I can get this information for both user A and B.

Any idea why this error occurs and what I can do to fix it?

Thanks!